# how to find the current priority of a thread in QNX

Tags: c, pthreads, qnx

Can any one tell me how to find the current priority of a thread in QNX.I had used pthread_getschedparam() function but this doesnt prints the expected value as the assigned and current are infact seen is the same.

The code snippet is shown below and the l_nRetVal returns 0 which is success.

```
    pthread_t thread_id = 0;
    struct sched_param  param_test;
    int l_nPolicy = -1;
    int l_nRetVal = -1;
char l_acMyPrio[20];

   memset( &param_test, 0, sizeof(param_test) );
   memset( l_acMyPrio, 0, sizeof(l_acMyPrio) );
   thread_id = pthread_self();
   l_nRetVal = pthread_getschedparam(thread_id, &l_nPolicy, &param_test);
```

regards
Maddy

Comment: Did you assign the priority anywhere? If not, what is the value you expected it to be and what did you actually get?

Comment: Side note: [you got the hungarian notation wrong](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HungarianNotation). [It's _good_ to mark a property of the variable, but _bad_ to mark it's type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Notable_opinions).

Comment: You need to show a bit more code than that.  It's not clear what you are setting and what you are printing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the `sched_curpriority` member of the `sched_param` structure to get the current priority of your thread.  Getting a value identical to what you set is quite normal. Reasons why you may legitimately expect a different value: 1. you are using sporadic scheduling policy; 2. the thread is in the middle of processing a message received via `MsgReceive()` and its relatives; 3 the thread is holding a mutex and a thread with a higher priority is blocked on the same mutex.

A sample (with error handling trimmed; NULL for the second parameter is a QNX extension):

```
   struct sched_param  param_test;

   pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), NULL, &param_test);
   printf("assigned_priority=%d; current_priority=%d\n", param_test.sched_priority, param_test.sched_curpriority);
```

Another sample in QNX documentation: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/s/sched_param.html